# What does a comma(,) syntax mean in bash script

Tags: bash, webpack, package.json

My console exited with code 0 after executing this line

`DEBUG=server,socket,redis nodemon --watch server server/src/index.js --ext js,graphql --exec babel-node`

this is a bash script which i'm trying to run in windows console

After changing it to `set DEBUG=server,...`, i tried to echo `DEBUG` but the whole string `server,socket,redis nodemon --watch server server/src/index.js --ext js,graphql --exec babel-node` is stored in `DEBUG`

I don't understand what does comma(`,`) do in this command, or should it be `&&` instead?

Comment: Looks OK to me, the DEBUG variable store arguments that belongs to npm run in this context, right ?
Comma shouldn't do anything if setting a environment variable like so

Comment: yup it belongs to npm run. so this is an expected behavior? what does comma mean anyway?

Comment: the comma is a seperator, so DEBUG can be overloaded with more than one option. BUT, you can't include the rest of the command in the `DEBUG=...` assignment. The `nodemon ...` is a separate command and in the MS environment needs to be on a separate line or maybe separated by a semicolon (`;`). Good luck.

Comment: I read that as inline assignment `DEBUG="server,socket,redis"` - just a string? - followed by the `nodemon` command. Is the comma actually *doing* something?

Comment: Regarding @shellter's last comment, are you sure you are actually *using* `bash`?

Comment: @shellter thanks for the explanation! yeah adding a separator helped, i used `&` as separator and it works now

Comment: @chepner not sure. i just thought that code is meant for bash but what i needed was for it to run in MS environment